# How can I query for all new and updated documents since last query?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I need to query a collection and return all documents that are new or updated since the last query.  The collection is partitioned by `userId`.  I am looking for a value that I can use (or create and use) that would help facilitate this query.  I considered using `_ts`:

```
SELECT * FROM collection WHERE userId=[some-user-id] AND _ts > [some-value]
```

The problem with `_ts` is that it is not granular enough and the query could miss updates made in the same second by another client.

In SQL Server I could accomplish this using an `IDENTITY` column in another table.  Let's call the table `version`.  In a transaction I would create a new row in the `version` table, do the updates to the other table (including updating the `version` column with the new value.  To query for new and updated rows I would use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE userId=[some-user-id] and version > [some-value]
```

How could I do something like this in Cosmos DB?  The Change Feed seems like the right option, but without the ability to query the Change Feed, I'm not sure how I would go about this.

In case it matters, the (web/mobile) clients connect to data in Cosmos DB via a web api.  I have control of the entire stack - from client to back-end.

Answer (score 0):

As the statements in this [link](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed#change-feed-and-different-operations):

> Today, you see all operations in the change feed. The functionality
>   where you can control change feed, for specific operations such as
>   updates only and not inserts is not yet available. You can add a “soft
>   marker” on the item for updates and filter based on that when
>   processing items in the change feed. Currently change feed doesn’t log
>   deletes. Similar to the previous example, you can add a soft marker on
>   the items that are being deleted, for example, you can add an
>   attribute in the item called "deleted" and set it to "true" and set a
>   TTL on the item, so that it can be automatically deleted. You can read
>   the change feed for historic items, for example, items that were added
>   five years ago. If the item is not deleted you can read the change
>   feed as far as the origin of your container.

Change feed is not available for your requirements.

My idea:

Use [Azure Function Cosmos DB Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function) to collect all the operations in your specific cosmos collection. Follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2) to configure the input of azure function as cosmos db, then follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue) to configure the output as azure queue storage.

Get the ids of changed items and send them into queue storage as messages.When you want to query the changed item,just query the messages from the queue to consume them at a specific unit time and after that just clear the entire queue. No items will be missed.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow how this would work. I would need to query the messages by userId and version/timestamp.  I can never delete the messages because a subsequent query may come in with the same userId but a different version/timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

With your approach, you can get added/updated documents and save reference value (_ts and id field) somewhere (like blob)

```
SELECT * FROM collection WHERE userId=[some-user-id] AND _ts > [some-value] and id !='guid' order by _ts desc
```

This is a similar approach we use to read data from Eventhub and store checkpointing information (epoch number, sequence number and offset value) in blob. And at a time only one function can take a lease of that blob.

If you go with ChangeFeed, you can create listener (Function or Job) to listen all add/update data from collection and you can store those value in some collection, while saving data you can add Identity/version field on every document. This approach may increase your cosmos DB bill.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the transaction consistency levels are for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels

Choose **strong consistency** and your queries will always return the latest write.

> Strong: Strong consistency offers a linearizability guarantee. The
>   reads are guaranteed to return the most recent committed version of an
>   item. A client never sees an uncommitted or partial write. Users are
>   always guaranteed to read the latest committed write.